# Extracting values in table

Tags: r

I know this seems to be over dependent on SO, but i am a beginner and worked on this for a couple of days but was not successful. I am able to do it for an individual table, but when it comes to list the code doesn`t work. I hope everyone understands the situation.

We have a list of elements in a list say:

```
ls<-list("N","E","E","N","P","E","M","Q","E","M")
```

We have an another list of tables in a list say:

```
n <- list("M", "N","E","P","Q","M","N","E","Q","N") 
tb <- lapply(1:10, function(i)matrix(sample(4), 2, 2, 
           dimnames=list(n[sample(10,2)], n[sample(2,2)])))
```

We need to extract values from the table in the list where colname is always "M" , wherein the rowname should be the 1st element in the list ls for table 1 in the list tb and 2nd element in table 2 and so on...

for example:

```
 M N 

N 4 1

P 3 2
```

In table 1 , we need to extract value 4.

Comment: this is very similar to your other question which was closed. I would suggest you a) try to learn R basics better (look at subset(tb[[1]],select="M")..., b) try to make simpler data structures c) listen to the comments people give you on SO [question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099095/filtering-a-list-based-on-values-in-a-different-list

Comment: Agree with Ido Tamir. Ram should have  at the very least included the code that he thought worked for an individual table. I have sympathy for persons who are by historical accident forced to communicate in English, but they should still be expected to use worked examples when the words fail them.

Answer (score 1):

I give up. Here is what I think might be close to the desired result , but 1) setting a seed for reproducibility, 2) changing the names to "ls1" and "n1" so they doesn't overlap with the `ls` function and are more 'specific':

```
set.seed(123)
tb <- lapply(1:10, function(i) matrix(sample(4), 2, 2, 
            dimnames=list( n1[sample(10,2)], n1[sample(2,2)])))
val <- rep(NA,10)
for (i in seq_along(tbls) ){    
  # will a need A test for both alpha values having  match with the two dimnames 
               rowidx <- which(dimnames(tb[[i]])[[1]] == ls1[[i]]) # often length==0
               colidx <- which(dimnames(tb[[i]])[[2]] == n1[[i]])
    if( length(rowidx) & length(colidx) ){ 
           val[i] <- tb[[i]][rowidx,colidx] 
                 } else { val[i] <- "not" }

> val
 [1] "1"   "not" "not" "not" "not" "not" "not" "not" "not" "2"
```

I rationalized providing a worked example under the hypothetical situation of being given a badly designed data structure that was produced by some external source and just needing to "cope". It does illustrate the use of seq_along as an index ,  the access of list structures with `[[`, and a way to handle lack of which/match possibilities. I still think this should NOT be used as a template for solving problems.

Comment: +1 for solution and public health warning

Comment: the point about bad data structures does remind me of the Maine joke: "if I wanted to get there, I wouldn't start from here ..." A little bit more context from the OP (are these indeed data structures they are stuck with, or could they change them to something that works better in R?) would be useful ...